# Проверка пользователя, WebSocket

Tags: websocket

При работе с AJAX, приходится все время делать проверку пользователя. Необходима ли такая проверка при работе с WebSoket'ами?

Comment: websocket это просто еще один вид транспорта данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет. При подключении к вебсокету происходит "рукопожатие" (handshake). В этот момент вы делаете проверку пользователя и до тех пор, пока соединение не разорвётся, вам её делать больше не нужно.